# Count records by field in laravel model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm looking the best way to get and array that count existent rows of some eloquent model by a certain field. Guest an Installation model with a type field. Right now Iam using this approach to do it

```
$typeCount = Installation::select('type', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count'))
  ->groupBy('type')
  ->get()
  ->mapWithKeys(function($item) {
        return [$item['type'] => $item['count']];
  })->toArray();
```

and $typeCount will return an array like this

```
[
     "contrib" => 2,
     "official" => 1,
]
```

Is there a better way or an elegant one????

Answer (score 2):

According to [pluck](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L715) method:

> Collection pluck(string $column, string|null $key = null)

Laravel will use the column value of **second parameter as key**, the column value of **first parameter as value**:

```php
$typeCount = Installation::select('type', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count'))
  ->groupBy('type')
  ->pluck('count', 'type')
  ->toArray();
```